# SQL - Define a column and use it in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I define a new column and use it in the same query?

For example,

```
Select 
    student, age + 10 as trueage, 
    case when trueage < 25 then 'False' else 'True' end
From 
    class
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: It is not possible. You probably don't understand the order of sql clause evaluation. Where conditions are evaluated first, matching rows are returned, then columns specified after select clause are evaluated. I think you can use "age + 10" in both places (in select clause and in where clause). Most of SQL engines will take care of it.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Netezza apparently allows this for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/24246283/73226

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. It's funny because Microsoft Access allows it, too.

Comment: @Konrad, here is a [good article](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/t-sql-tuesday-017-it-slices-it-dices-it.html) showing many ways to use `CROSS APPLY`. One of them is to "Introduce New Columns".

Answer (score 4):

[`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) would be handy here. Here is a [nice article](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/t-sql-tuesday-017-it-slices-it-dices-it.html) showing many uses of it.

```
Select
    student
    ,trueage
    ,case when trueage < 25 then 'False' else 'True' end
From
    class
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT age + 10 as trueage
    ) AS CA
```

It is mostly useful when you have complex formulas with several levels, something like this:

```
Select
    student
    ,trueage
    ,AgeFlag
From
    class
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT age + 10 as trueage
    ) AS CA1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT case when trueage < 25 then 'False' else 'True' end AS AgeFlag
    ) AS CA2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using a subquery "same query" then yes.

```
select student,
       trueAge,
       case when trueAge < 25 then 'false' else 'true' end as someColumn
from ( 
    select student, age + 10 as trueAge
    from table
) thingy
```

There are likely other ways to do this as well, this is only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
  Select student, age + 10 as trueage, 
   case when (age + 10) < 25 then 'False' else 'True' end 
   from class
```